# Remove spaces on filename windows

Tags: windows, filenames, rename, batch-rename

Can someone help me to remove spaces in a filename of windows.

Example:

```
   ABCD001 _V01.DOC >>>> ABCD001_V01.DOC
   ABCD002 _V01.DOC >>>> ABCD002_V01.DOC
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer):

```
$ renamer --find "/\s/g" --dry-run *
```

This will remove all whitespace from filenames in the current directory. Once you're happy the output looks correct, remove the `--dry-run` flag.

Comment: renamer does not seem to work on my pc.. does it require to install anything to make use of this command?

Comment: did you follow the installation instructions on the github page? you need to install node.js (see http://nodejs.org) then run the "nom install -g renamer" command

Answer (score 0):

Test this on some sample files first:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
   set "line=%%~nxa"
   ren "%%a" "!line: =!"
)
```